# excel error 1004 unable to get the countifs property of worksheetfunction class appear

Tags: vba, excel

hello i really hoping someone can help me with this.
i want to use countifs in VBA using 3 criteria and has this script

```
Sub Count()
Dim DateSmall As Date
Dim DateBig As Date
Dim Company As String


DateSmall = CDate(Sheet2.Range("C28"))
DateBig = CDate(Sheet2.Range("E28"))
Company = Sheet2.Range("B28").Value


Set rGo = Sheet1.Range("E10", Sheet1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rCompany = Sheet1.Range("C10", Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

CountIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rGo, ">=" & DateSmall, rGo, "<=" & DateBig, rCompany, Company)


MsgBox CountIn

End Sub
```

but it got error 1004 but when i use 2 criteria using the same script i can this is the script using 2 criteria

```
Sub Count()
Dim DateSmall As Date
Dim DateBig As Date



DateSmall = CDate(Sheet2.Range("C28"))
DateBig = CDate(Sheet2.Range("E28"))


Set rGo = Sheet1.Range("E10", Sheet1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

CountIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rGo, ">=" & DateSmall, rGo, "<=" & DateBig)


MsgBox CountIn

End Sub
```

i hope someona can help me with this . . .

```
Sheet 1
02-Oct-14   SSI
02-Oct-14   SSI
02-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SCI
03-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SCI
02-Oct-14   JSU
02-Oct-14   JSU
30-Sep-14   JSU

Sheet 2
SSI     1-Jan-14        10-Jan-16
```

Comment: I don't get any error :(

Comment: i got error on first script but not from secnd sccript

Comment: I don't get error in First code also.  May be the cell values causing the error.

Comment: u mean the values in the excel cell ?? where the company in ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is the range for rGO and rCompany is different.

IMPORTANT: Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

For more details information, you can refer to 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Hope this help.

Comment: It has the same range . . . same count row

Comment: can show your data from sheet1, column C and column E?

Comment: In the meanwhile, try to substitute the rCompany into rGo and see whether the error still happen or not.

Comment: Sheet 1
02-Oct-14 SSI
02-Oct-14 SSI
02-Oct-14 SSI
03-Oct-14 SSI
03-Oct-14 SSI
03-Oct-14 SSI
07-Oct-14 SSI
07-Oct-14 SSI
07-Oct-14 SCI
03-Oct-14 SSI
06-Oct-14 SSI
06-Oct-14 SSI
06-Oct-14 SSI
06-Oct-14 SSI
06-Oct-14 SSI
03-Oct-14 SSI
07-Oct-14 SCI
02-Oct-14 JSU
02-Oct-14 JSU
30-Sep-14 JSU

sheet 2

Comment: it is very hard to see, can you update it in your code above by modify it?

Comment: can you try to substitute the rCompany into rGo and see whether the error still happen or not.

Comment: the only thing i can think of is the range is different. Try to use check the region of your rCompany and rGo, to check whether same range or not.

Comment: how to check range the region of rcompany and rgo?

Comment: click on the data, then press [Ctrl] + [A]

Comment: if in collumn B has 32 row data and Collumn C has 30 row data 
i cant Countifs it ??

Comment: According to the microsoft support website, it need to be same.

Comment: weird when i try it can but when i do it for a big data it cant 
when i try small data it cant and then can . . . weird

Comment: try to use fixed set of data first, only try to convert to auto detect region (xlUp/xlDown).

Comment: how i use fixed set of data ?? oo and i found it something like this it can do a countifs  even there is different row of it as long as the last row of them has data in it

Comment: i think this is not a chit chat place. Since you found the error already, happy programming ya~ ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
Sheet 1
02-Oct-14   SSI
02-Oct-14   SSI
02-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SCI
03-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
06-Oct-14   SSI
03-Oct-14   SSI
07-Oct-14   SCI
02-Oct-14   JSU
02-Oct-14   JSU
30-Sep-14   JSU

sheet 2
SSI    1-Jan-14     10-Jan-16
```